# Background images will not resize on iPhone and iPad. Nothing has worked

Tags: ios, css, iphone, resize

This is where I believe the problem to be.

Let me know if I'm wrong.

```
/* Home Style */
#tf-home{
    background: url(../img/kristen11.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #cfcfcf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`background-attachment: scroll;`

instead of fixed as ios specially iphone and ipad has issue with `background-attachment: fixed`